# Twilio security implementation . x-twilio-signature not matching with computed value

Tags: c#, security, base64, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to implement twilio security as mentioned in https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security

I have tried the implementation in both .net and php but not able to validate the request

My .net implementation code looks like as following

```
    SortedDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
    {
        //{"SmsId", "4176669"},
        //{"TelcoId", "-5"},
        {"SmsSid", "SMa97c925c6169475a88074082712b68ac"},
        {"SmsStatus", "sent"},
        {"MessageStatus", "sent"},
        {"To", "+***********"},
        {"MessageSid", "SMa97c925c6169475a88074082712b68ac"},
        {"AccountSid", "*********************************"},
        {"From", "+**********"},
        {"ApiVersion", "2010-04-01"}
    };

    var url = "http://*****************************?SmsId=4176665&TelcoId=-5";
    var authtoken = "********************************";
    var _hmac = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authtoken));


    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(url);
    foreach (var v in dictionary)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(v.Key);
        stringBuilder.Append(v.Value);
    }
    string xTwilioSignature = "+HvlkGkyMxo9rEVjlJ4hhD/sSaw=";

    string computed = Convert.ToBase64String(_hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString())));
    bool result1 = xTwilioSignature == computed;
    bool restul2 = SecureCompare(xTwilioSignature, computed);


    private static bool SecureCompare(string a, string b)
    {
        if (a == null || b == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int length = a.Length;
        if (length != b.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            num = num | a[i] ^ b[i];
        }
        return num == 0;
    }
```

Please help me in identifying what wrong i am doing

Comment: Is this for a status callback for a message that you sent? And where are you getting the fields from? Presumably you're not using a static dictionary of values like in this example, do you get them from the incoming request? You seem to be missing the `Body` parameter in this example at least.

Comment: Thanks Philnash. I were able to resolve the problem by correction in the url and removing couple of additional paramters [smsid and telcoid which are already there in the url]

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted!

Comment: My impelemtation for .net core 3.0 application breaks. Post bug on github is https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/509

Comment: I've asked internally for someone with more C# experience than me to take a look at that, but it looks like your suggestion is correct that we assume standard port numbers even if it's present in the URL.

Comment: Thanks  @philnash . It would more help if someone could also reply on github post

Comment: I can see the team are looking at this right now. Thanks for following up with answers. 